# Como manipular DIV com angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, javascript-eventos, angular2-directives

Tenho 2 DIVs e gostaria de manipula-las com botoes. Tenho 2 DIVs. Quando uma aparece a outra fica oculta, vice-versa. Alguém pode me ajudar ? a minha versão do Angular é a 5.

Funcao1
   Funcao2

conteudo -2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## app.component.ts

```
public div: boolean = true;
```

## app.component.html

```
<a (click)="div = 1">div1 show</a>
<div *ngIf="div">
 div 1 
</div>
<br>
<a (click)="div = 0">div2 show</a>
<div *ngIf="!div">
 div 2
</div>
```

Você pode esta usando função `(click)="div = 0; funcao()" ou (click)="funcao()" funcao(){ this.div = !this.div; }`

<sup>[***Funcionando onlline***](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzwdyy)</sup>

Comment: Boa amigo...Deu certo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Fique atento que a div não fica oculta mas e removida do dom

Comment: sim, Eduardo mais não era viável removela do dom, pois ele ira reutiliza-la